# eclipse not generate annotation process class but m2e-apt works fine

Tags: java, eclipse, undertow

There is a class in undertow named `HttpRequestParser` that uses annotation process and should generate `HttpRequestParser$$generated`.

Firstly, m2e-apt works fine because it generate `generated-sources` correctly.

I try to run example

```java
        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
                    }
                }).build();
        server.start();
```

But with error

```
Mar 27, 2019 10:50:55 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.8.Final
Mar 27, 2019 10:50:55 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.8.Final
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser$$generated
    at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:247)
    at io.github.fairjm.undertow.examples.HelloWorldServer.main(HelloWorldServer.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser$$generated
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser.instance(HttpRequestParser.java:221)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.<init>(HttpOpenListener.java:93)
    at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:179)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser$$generated
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser.instance(HttpRequestParser.java:216)
    ... 3 more
```

`UndertowLogger_$logger` has been generated by m2e-apt so log is ok.

And I try to run `mvn clean compile`, then `HttpRequestParser$$generated` is genereated in the `target\classes`(and it has no source generated).

What do I need to do making eclipse generate them?

Answer (score 0):

Emmmmm...
I feel so embarrassed..
During typing I asked myself have I add the processor jar to factory path and then I checked it found no...
After put `undertow-parser-generator` to `undertow-core` ast factory path.
It finally works.

[image]